# Get the ChartSpace from a ChartReference

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

I try to modify a PowerPoint Slide, which contains two Charts. My goal is to find the Chart and modify its data.

I already got the GraphicFrame which contains the Chart, and I got the relative ID of the ChartSpace Element I want to modify. But how to get the actucal ChartSpace element?

```
 public void test()
{
    //// getting the SlidePart
      var slidepart = presPart.GetPartById(relId) as SlidePart;
    //// getting the Shape which contains the damned Chart
    var graphicFrame = GetGraphicFrameFromSlide(slidepart, ppChart, ppSlide);
    //// get the ChartReference
    DrawCharts.ChartReference child = GraphicFrame.Graphic.GraphicData.GetFirstChild<DrawCharts.ChartReference>();
                                var chartID = child.Id;
    //// this returns a ExtendedSomething, but no chart reference :(
                               var chartData = presDoc.GetPartById(chartID) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian, if you are still looking for an answer: I was able to find one for my question. I think it may be useful for you too.

Refer to post "[Finding a graph part within a rich text control with OpenXML SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811193/finding-a-graph-part-within-a-rich-text-control-with-openxml-sdk)".

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps you, but I am doing something like this in a Word document:

```
        foreach (ChartPart chartPart in mainDocumentPart.ChartParts)
        {
            Chart chart = chartPart.ChartSpace.Elements<Chart>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (chart != null)
            {

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.LineChart lineChart = chart.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.LineChart>().FirstOrDefault();

                if (lineChart != null)
                {
                    i++;

                    LineChartEx chartEx = new LineChartEx(chartPart, myChartData));
                    chartEx.Refresh();
                }
            }

            chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();

        }
```

For the moment I'm still trying to figure out how to retrieve a chart that resides within a given rich text control (using it's tag name). The above method works, but I'm not completely happy with it.

Anyway, good luck finding a solution to your problem!

Comment: Thank you,. that looks very similar to my own approach, which I build today. Good that my logic was not tottaly of the mark :)
As a suggestion: you can give namepsaces aliases like: Draw = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
that would shorten your query drastically.